# Issue with laravel route with Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have my main container (app.blade.php) and inside it I have my home.blade, inside there is a container that refreshes with ajax after clicking an item in the sidenav menu. If you click one of those items when the session has expired, a middleware redirects you to the login (or at least it’s meant to). This should happen

[God login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUXvs.png)

The issue is that, when that event happens, it renders the login inside of the container refreshed with ajax, like in the picture below. Any idea of how to solve this?

[Bad login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywyyM.png)

(Sorry if i have issues in my writing, i am still learning english and in stackoverflow in spanish nobody helps :/)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please make sure to include [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "middleware" is working OK, it is doing what is meant to do: Any petition to the server is transformed in a redirection to your login page. However, you are making an async call. I guess you are rendering whatever the result is in a container, resulting in your "bad login".

A possible solution is to add some parameter to your ajax requests in order to catch it on the server side and send you an error status instead of a redirection, then in your page handle that error as a browser redirection to your login.